# How can I scrape only h3 tag's items?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I want to scrape only h3 tag's items.HTML is like

```
<h3 class="index_title">
    <a href="/test/1112">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit                          
    </a>
</h3>
```

I wrote codes,

```
var Crawler = require("node-webcrawler");
var url = require('url');
var connection = require('./mysqlConnection'); 

var c = new Crawler({
  maxConnections : 10,
  callback : function (error, result, $) {
      if(error){
          console.log(error);
      }else{
        const titles = $(".index_title");
          for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i ++){
            const title = $(titles[i]).text();
            var query = 'INSERT INTO crawling (title) VALUES ("' + title + '")';
            connection.query(query, function(err, rows) {
              console.log(err);
            });
          }
      }
  }
});
　c.queue('https://xxxxxxx.jp/');
```

When I run the codes,`"                                 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"`  in DB,so useless space is in there.I want to only get Lorem ipsum~~ letters but I think a tag in h3 tag causes this strange thing.I rewrote

```
const titles = $(".index_title").trim();
```

but in this time TypeError: $(...).trim is not a function error happens.What is wrong in my codes?How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

### THE ISSUE

#### INITIAL ANALYSIS

It looks like the issue you were running into was because jQuery gives you back a list of native `DOM` elements instead of giving you a `jQuery` element to work with. I suspect it has something to do with using the vanilla loop and not some method provided by `jQuery` itself.

#### FINAL CONCLUSION

After working with both the pure javascript and jquery versions below, it seems like `$('...')` gives you a list of native `DOM` elements, regardless the loop structure. What I didn't realize, however, is that you'd then have to convert the node retrieved INTO a `jquery` element (seen at `$(this)`), which is definitely not very desirable. For transparency, both code snippets are available in their working, minimal form below.

#### Minimal, working code example:

```js
// jQuery only
$(".index_title").each(function() {
  const title = $(this).text().trim();
  console.log(title);
});


// Javascript only
const titles = document.getElementsByClassName('index_title');
for(var i = 0; i < titles.length; i ++) {
  const title = titles[i].innerText.trim();
  console.log(title);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h3 class="index_title">
      <a href="/test/1112">
              1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit                          
      </a>
   </h3>
  <h3 class="index_title">
     <a href="/test/1112">
              2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit                          
     </a>
  </h3>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer.When I run your codes,ReferenceError: document is not defined error happens.How should I do it?

Comment: If document is undefined, you should use the jquery only version instead.

Comment: I am using Node.js.Should I use jQuery necessary?